# How to crop a particular part of a YouTube video clip?

Tags: video, video-editing, video-encoding, youtube

Having an MPEG4 (MP4 container, H264 AVC video, AAC audio) video clip downloaded from YouTube, how to crop a particular piece of it (remove everything before a particular starting point timestamp an after a particular finish point timestamp) with free Linux tools?

PS: I don't mind employing a patented or even a BLOB codec library.

Comment: Does the fact that it's from YouTube matter somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, but I am not sure. I've specified it for my question to be more precise and the example to be more practical. As far as I know codecs and containers are a messy subject with tons of variations and incompatible implementations, so, maybe, it does matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mencoder](http://mplayerhq.hu/) (in your distribution, it should come in the package `mplayer`). If you wanted to extract 3 minutes starting at 21:50, you would do

```
mencoder -ss 21:50 -endpos 3:00 your-video.mp4 -o output.mp4 -oac copy -ovc copy
```

It's not exact: the starting point will be adjusted to the beginning of a frame. It's possible to work around this, if it's a problem (usually it isn't).

Comment: mencoder: Symbol `ff_codec_bmp_tags' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
MEncoder SVN-r33713-4.6.1 (C) 2000-2011 MPlayer Team
-endpoint is not an MEncoder option

Comment: Sorry, it's `endpos`. My mistake. -- Fixed.

Comment: It worked, but... 1. `Audio format 0x4134504d is incompatible with '-oac copy', please try '-oac pcm' instead or use '-fafmttag' to override it` (I've used PCM succesfully) 2. `WARNING: OUTPUT FILE FORMAT IS _AVI_` - seriously?

Comment: AVI is the default. See `mencoder -of help` for a list of available output formats. In any case, you could extract audio and video separately (`-novideo` or `-ovc null`, `-nosound` or `-oac null`) and then put them together using another tool, like `mkvmerge`.